# Nonsense UICollectionViewCell height will be 0 at run time warning

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, storyboard, uicollectionviewcell

I know this problem -generally- occurs when you set the constraints wrong or when you miss setting one or more constraints. But my problem is different.

I have a UICollectionViewController and a cell in if of course. All of the constraints are set as expected. Such that here is a screenshot of it, when the cell is not in collectionView, in controller stack:

[image: cell in controller stack]

But when I put it inside collectionView; it becomes:

[image]

And this is view stack of the controller;

[image]

On runtime, everything works perfectly -as expected- though.

So I decided to change the controller. Deleted current controller and added a brand new one and added the cell to it. Whoops! Everything is fine!
But when I change anything on the controller, or on the cell, it doesn't matter, even when I set a new identifier to the cell, it becomes broken again. (Yes, I'm serious, setting an identifier to the cell brokes it.)

How can I solve this issue anyone knows?

This project is not mine, I will hand over to the project owner soon and who knows who will work on it later, so I cannot explain the problem, and everything would become messy.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I just wasted over an hour trying to figure this out, it just feels like a waste of time.

Comment: Nope. This should be a bug. I just learned how to live with it and ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the collection view out of the stack view it was in and redoing constraints in place of the stack view seems to have fixed the issue.

Best of luck and hope that helps!